# How can I iterate through and insert a line of one file into another file, creating a new file each time?

Tags: text-processing

I have File 1 that contains:

```
"text1"
"text2"
"text3"
"text4"
```

etc, through "text2000". note - the quotes are included.

I have another file that contains a script of code.

I want to go through File 1 and place "textx" into the file with the script of code, creating a new file each time. So I should create 2000 files. I also want to name each file from 1.js-2000.js.

Eg, the resulting file would have:

```
"Text1"

base code
```

How could I do this? For reference, I am currently attempting using bash, but open to other options.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your example file as code so we can be sure of what you mean. Show us an example input file (as you have, but formatted so we can read it and only include the quotes if they are actually part of the file), and then also show us the output file(s) you would expect from that input. Finally, please also add your operating system to the question and explain why node.js is relevant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. Re-formatted the question. To clarify, the base code file script is a .js file but I don't think it affects this question much, I can probably just have its code in a txt file right for this purpose?

Comment: Ah, OK. Yeah, we don't care what kind of text the code is, for this exercise it is just text and whether it's node.js code or C++ code or a cake recipe makes no difference. And thanks for the edit, that's much clearer!

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to do in the shell:

```
c=0
while IFS= read -r text; do 
  {
    printf '%s\n' "$text"
    cat file2
  } > "newFile$((c += 1))"
done < file1
```

Here, `file1` has the text strings you want to add and `file2` is your code. I tested this on a small `file2` which had 96 lines of shell code and a `file1` with 2000 strings and it took around 4 seconds on my machine. If your `file2` is very large, however, you should think of using a different language and/or approach.

Answer (score 1):

Small tweaks to @terdon's answer, using `bash`:

- I assume you actually want to uppercase the first letter
- no external commands invoked in the loop helps performance.

```bash
# read the code file just once
code=$(< scriptFile)

c=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    prefix=${line%%[[:alpha:]]*}    # the leading non-alpha chars of $line
    text=${line#"$prefix"}          # the rest of the line

    printf '%s%s\n\n%s\n' "$prefix" "${text^}" "$code" > "newFile${c}"
    ((++c))
done < file1
```

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, Glenn, but please don't feel you need to make this community wiki because it's "small" tweaks to mine! What's minor to you is not minor to others, and apart from the main idea of using a loop and a counter, which is pretty obvious and the way anyone would have done it, this is a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    code = code ORS $0
    next
}
{
    print $0 ORS code > (FNR ".js")
    close(FNR ".js")
}
' codefile file1
```

Comment: this worked great, thank you all for the help!

Comment: is the a line I could add to this so that the files are named number.js instead of just a number?

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the script to add `.js` to the output file name but please edit your question to change `I also want to name each file from 1-2,000` to `I also want to name each file from 1.js-2000.js` so it's clear.

Comment: revised the question, thanks!